# Variable pass is already defined in method onclickregister(View)

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords, match

I am trying to run a code for matching passwords. I do not understand the error message:

> variable pass is already defined in method onclickregister(View)

**CODE:**

```
package com.example.admin.rent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}

public void onclickregister(View view) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.register)
    {
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText sname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);
        EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText mnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileno);
        EditText pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass1);

        String namestr = name.getText().toString();
        String snamestr = sname.getText().toString();
        String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
        String mnumstr = mnum.getText().toString();
        String passstr = pass.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();

        if(!passstr.equals(pass1str))
        {
            //popup msg
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Register.this , "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }


    }
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.admin.rent.Register">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/name"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/surname"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/surname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobileno"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pass1"
    android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="+91"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/surname"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center|clip_vertical"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mobileno" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/mobileno"
    android:layout_below="@+id/surname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/register2"
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:width="170dp"
    android:onClick="onclickregister" />
```

Comment: Not sure what error message you're referring to. All you included was some code and an xml layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the pass variable in that inner scope:

```
    if(!passstr.equals(pass1str))
    {
        //popup msg
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Register.this , "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        pass.show();
    }
```

to something else. The problem is that you already have a variable with that name defined in the outer scope:

```
        EditText pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
```